# Can't access an input value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a web page with a table to input data. Adding/deleting a row works, but the added row copies the data of the first line.
I'm using:

```
jquery
bootstrap  
globalize    
jquery.dataTables
query.table.addrow
```

I can't access the numeric values. I want to:

1. give the numbers a default value of 0 for the inputs.
2. get the values and use them to calculate other values in the page.

The html:

```
          <form class="form-horizontal">
            <table id="tabc" border="1"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-condensed datatable" style="width:auto;margin:30px">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th title="Masa en gramos" >Masa(g)</th>
                  <th>Analito</th>
                  <th title="Concentración del standard">Std</th> 
                  <th>Volumen</th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="number" class="input-mini" name="ryacur" id="ryacur1" ></td>
                  <td><input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source='["Ag","Al","As","Au","Ba","Be","Bi","Br","Cr","Pb","Pd"]' autocomplete="off" class="input-mini" name="anacur" id="anacur1" ></td>
                  <td><input type="number" class="input-mini" name="stdcur" id="stdcur1" ></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td><input type="button" class="AddNew" value="Agrega"></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
             <div class="span2 offset3"><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" style="color:darkblue"></div>
          </form>
```

The js:

```
$('#tabc').dataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
        "sUrl": "/arch/es_CL.js"
    },
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": true
});


$('.AddNew').click(function () {
    var row = $('#tabc tbody tr:last-child'),
        newRow = row.clone(),
        oTable = $('#tabc').dataTable();
    newRow.find("input", newRow).each(function () {
        this.val = '';
        var num = +(this.id.match(/\d+$/) || [0])[0] + 1
        this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + num;
        console.log(this.val); // <<<<<<<<<<< Doesn't work
        $('input[type="button"]', newRow).removeClass('AddNew').addClass('RemoveRow').val('Borra');
    });
    newRow.insertAfter(row);
});

$('table').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this `console.log(this.val);` to

`console.log(this.value);` Or `console.log($(this).val());`

Comment: `value` is DOM property whereas `.val()` is jquery method,,SO you cant use `this.val()` or `$(this).value` ..As `this` represent DOM element and `$(this)` represent jQuery object